# How Can i Disable autoplay video in Iframe Dailymotion?

Tags: html, iframe

How Can i Disable autoplay video in Iframe Dailymotion?

```
*<iframe scrolling="no" src="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5qfmca"></iframe>*
```

Comment: How can i Control Iframe 2 sources video, to play one after the other. i mean after 1st source video completes it should continue (auto-play)next (iframe src) video in the same frame code

*<iframe scrolling="no" src1="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x5qfmca"></iframe>*

my next src2= "http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xpt9ov" [should load automatically after src1]

Answer (score 0):

From Dailymotion docs:

> `allow="autoplay"` attribute to delegate the autoplay permission from
>   the origin once received, as specified by the Feature Policy for
>   autoplay specification. If this isn't set, the player will not be able
>   to play without a user gesture.

By default autoplay is disabled.

If you see below:

> Note: this parameter may not work on some mobile OS versions as most
>   mobile devices prevent the video from auto playing to save user's
>   bandwidth.

Can you provide more info about decides which you are experiencing this issue?

More docs in: https://developer.dailymotion.com/player